# C# switch between forms inside a form like in MSN

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, msn, msn-messenger

I remember MSN Messenger used to display a login. And upon logging in, it displayed a loading animation. On success it displayed all your contacts. All that in one single form.

How is that done?

I dont only know how to make new forms, or display forms inside forms. But that is not how its done, right?

---

I am opened to suggestions on how to improve my question. I know I barely could explain myself. Perhaps with your help, i can edit my question to be more helpful to others

Comment: It is likely that they aren't forms within forms but rather controls within forms, particularly container controls.   For example, you can make custom control classes within the designer that will hold several other controls and basically behave like a form.  As far as forms within forms go, you can look into [multiple document interface (MDI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You might be looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984329(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @J.i.h, i think you are totally right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user the UserControl object. You can dock them to a panel in the main form.

This example uses a Panel object in the main form for docking (named pnlCentre).

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    DummyControl1 dummy1;
    DummyControl2 dummy2;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        dummy1 = new DummyControl1();
        dummy2 = new DummyControl2();

        pnlCentre.Controls.Add(dummy1);
        pnlCentre.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
    // switches between screens
    public void switchscreen()
    {
        pnlCentre.Controls.Remove(dummy1);
        pnlCentre.Controls.Add(dummy2);
        pnlCentre.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }

}

public partial class DummyControl1 : UserControl
{
    // can be filled from the designer
}

public partial class DummyControl2 : UserControl
{
    // can be filled from the designer
}
```

Comment: sorry for not accepting your answer in such a long time. I am new to c#, that i understood your answer only today. it is EXACTLY what i needed!

Comment: If you would be so nice to tell me how can i fill DummyControl1 from the designer?

Comment: nevermind. here is the link that explains it all. Anyone in need - enjoy:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/114xc3e5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I forgot i had answered this... I'm glad you figured out the rest on your own. If I need to clarify anything else let me know